# Im unable to scroll in Blender

Tags: animation

For the past few days, I'm trying to find how to get my scrolling back
when I try to do work It's just doesn't scroll down or up (the white blank page)
It's annoying me and if anyone knows how to bring it back?
I even reset to open the default settings file but it doesn't work
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is it your first time in blender ,  you move around by holding the middle mouse button. Moreover , if you want to zoom in and out you can scroll you middle mouse button and it wonk work if you are in middle of drawing something like a line or a curve , confirm the draw by middle mouse button click or ENTER.

Comment: But  i dont want to use mouse . I can zoom in but ...  im unable to scroll .This is in my laptop so i need to use scroller every time i zoom in i have to touch the scroll using my touch pad.... so .... If u know any short root  to scroll using just keyboard? Or something

Comment: im really not aware about what you are asking but even im on laptop and i also have a mouse , but do you want to scroll down and up , theres no need of doing that

Comment: Im really sorry ab this ....... i used blender like literally after 1 month n i forgot i used to use the hand (move the view) in right of the screenshot.... above the toggle view .... I immediately rushed here to comment thiss  after i remembered